# How can we group by one column and then need to group other column values in comma separated in DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

Eg:

| Department | Customer Name |
| --- | --- |
| CSE | A |
| CSE | B |
| IT | D |
| CSE | A |
| ECE | C |
| EEE | B |
| ECE | F |

Output:

| Department | Customer Name |
| --- | --- |
| CSE | A,B |
| IT | D |
| ECE | C,F |
| EEE | B |

Answer (score 1):

Try this DAX measure

```
Measure =
CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( tbl[Customer] ), tbl[Customer], "," )
```

[image: s1]

Comment: Could you please suggest how to use Filter within Concatenatex such that I filter only to priority Customer name i.e, Is Priority is Yes values should be concatenated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **Power Query** by adding these below 5 steps to your table's **Advance Query Editor**

Please adjust the **PREVIOUS_STEP_NAME** in the code as per your last step name.

```
let
    //............,
    //............ all previous steps,
    
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"PREVIOUS_STEP_NAME"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Department"}, {{"all name", each _, type table [Department=nullable text, Customer Name=nullable text]}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each [all name][Customer Name]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"all name"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Here is the output-

[image]

**But**, if you wants to keep your base table unchanged, just create a new table pointing the base table as source and perform those above steps.